# Phonegap Build remote push notifications without plugins?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

There appears to be no clear answer to this specific question, so I'm hoping someone can point out if **remote** push notifications on the client device (specifically iOS and Android) can be enabled if using PhoneGap Build and **not** using plugins like UrbanAirship. So the requirements are:

- Remote (not local) push notifications on client device
- Ability to enable remote notifications without 3rd party plugins
- Using PhoneGap Build to compile the client application

Building the server-side won't be a problem, but I really do like the PhoneGap Build service. If this is possible to do, what are the rough requirements on the client source (i.e.: Apple/Dev cert, special directory outside of `www`, etc.)

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Nothing concrete yet, but it looks like it requires development of a PhoneGap Build plugin. However, the Build Cloud everyday grows support for more custom plugins, so it's getting closer. I'll post an answer if I have a result :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a lot of time and research, as well as changes in the PhoneGap Build service, the definite answer is no this cannot be achieved without a plugin. It requires native code to execute the request for a device token.

As of August 2012 the progress on the PhoneGap Build service has been slow but there is a lot going on in the background. PGB will host/developed plugins themselves, and since a non-Build plugin for push notifications already exists it's likely that a new plugin will be developed for the Build service.

In the meantime, you'll need to build your app locally or simply play the waiting game.